# How to find Android virtualbox address?

Tags: android, virtualbox

I want to push an apk to my android device running in virtualbox. But i don't know the address of the android virtualbox. please show me a way to find my address.

Answer (score 0):

Type **ipconfig** in the command prompt of your host machine, and it should show up there.  If not, make sure you configured a network adapter for that device in VirtualBox.